# Moderator diamond is too large relative to other text on Android

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, android

This is very painful to look at. We understand appearances are everything, but there's no need to exaggerate. Could you please bring them back down to regular size?

It also throws off the formatting layouts. The top of the diamond is cut off on every post, and it expands the comment box by about two or three pixels.

Browser: Chrome for Android (Nexus 7, Jellybean 4.1). Screenshot is in desktop mode, though the problem is present in normal view as well.

> [image: screenshot of diamond largess]

- Reproduced in [Android 4.2.2 on Nexus 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Fvl.png) and to a lesser extent on [Firefox for Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi7Eq.png)
- Seen on 4.1.1 Jelly Bean - [reported by Seth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/203389/seth)

Comment: I get the same thing on Linux… sometimes. I’m not sure when or why. (Not quite that big, though.)

Comment: I have the same problem on the regular Android browser on a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2.

Comment: Same problem with Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3

Comment: They're just compensating. ;-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Certainly not to be confused with an ego-indicator. ;) /* Just kidding… */

Comment: Seems more like a CSS rendering bug than an intentional design choice. Suggest rephrasing your question to be more about the actual issue, rather than posing it as a design choice that was made by the design/dev on the site.

Comment: @Chad, I guess it's just a different font (as used by the browser to render that character). But surely that's indeed not a design choice either.

Comment: @Chad I never claimed it was a design choice, only that it's incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard corroboration of this problem for the mobile side but I haven't been able to reproduce this (or find someone who has) as of today, so I think it's likely that the [recently-refreshed mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234717/mobile-web-refresher) has probably obsoleted the problem.  I don't have a good explanation for why it would have appeared on the desktop site, but still: I can't reproduce, so we'll call it completed.

Comment: Looks like it's fixed, as I can't repro the problem on the latest Chrome for Android (37) on the desktop site.