# Comment font sizes are inconsistent on Android

Tags: bug, comments, design, android

An issue similar to that described in [Moderator diamond is too large relative to other text on Android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176715/your-jewels-are-much-too-big-moderator-diamond-is-too-large-relative-to-other) and likely to be related.

The comments for a question may vary in size:

> [image]

Chrome for Android on Nexus 7 running 4.2.2 Jelly Bean. This also occurs on Firefox for Android:

> [image]

Comment: Who is this Adam Davis fellow and why are his comments being blown up like ours?

Comment: That might be the very annoying feature of mobile Chrome to shrink text it regards as less important.

Comment: It's not just Android where this can be seen. On my Mac, on Area 51, the diamond next to the mods is huge, but *only* on Area 51, and only on my Mac. On Ubuntu, the diamonds are normal size on all SE sites, and I run Ubuntu in VirtualBox on the Mac. I use Chrome in both platforms.

Comment: Tread softly, but carry a big stick, er diamond...

Comment: Additional notes: If I use a Bluetooth mouse on my tablet, each time I mouse over or off the comment, space is inserted above the text of the comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ndY9n.png