# Are humorous question titles allowed, even if they don't accurately describe the problem?

Tags: discussion, title, humor

The [edit history of this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/176715/revisions) involves several edits to the title.  The title was initially the humorous "*Your jewels are much too big!*", but has since been changed to [Moderator diamond is too large relative to other text on Android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176715/moderator-diamond-is-too-large-relative-to-other-text-on-android).

Are humorous titles allowed, even if they don't accurately describe the problem?  We want to see a sense of humor here on Stack Exchange, but we also need to make sure question titles represent the problem to be solved.

Comment: A better example of a humorous title: [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](http://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)

Comment: [Question title that doesn't describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Obviously a ironic, tongue-in-cheek case.

Comment: See also: [Why do people have a little pun with their retag and burninate requests?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests) (["Should we cut corners"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295233/798371) remains a favorite pun-title for me, even if it's no longer on the question.)

Comment: Humorous titles are okay if they still describe the problem: [How the f*&% to stop voice-to-text from censoring profanity?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12578/267)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two key problems with humorous titles:

1. They become more difficult to find. Who else in the world is going to be searching for keywords like "jewels" when trying to ask a question about moderator diamonds on a mobile device?
2. It's hard to tell what the question is about. Not every list on the site always provides a short blurb from it, and a random, vaguely relevant title in a long list certainly isn't going to be very helpful.

Humorous titles are acceptable *to an extent*, but they should still contain accurate keywords that *describe the problem* so that other users with the same issue can find it easier (we already have enough problems with people trying to find things on Meta).

Comment: You forgot to mention (3) People are not often as funny as they think. <grin>

Comment: The "title: subtitle" model can work well here, e.g. [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).  The first part alone would be pretty meaningless and unsearchable, but with the second part it works.