# Render Differences

Tags: bug, design, android

Visiting Super User, via my Nexus 4 in full site modus, gives the following screenshot:
[image: Super User screen shot]

Visiting Web Applications however, yields the following shot:
[image: Web Applications screen shot]

Apart from the content, the alignment of Super User Site is too much to the left. This makes it difficult to select your inbox or notifications.

Nexus 4, Chrome Beta 29.

Update: 06-08-2013
Super User
[image: Super User]

Web Applications
[image: Web Applications]

Comment: I am clearly blind.  Where exactly is the difference?

Comment: @Ramhound the Stack Exchange icon in the pull down menu (upper left corner), is aligned straight to the left side of the screen. In the webapps.se screenshot, there's still a bit of empty space left. I've seen it only on Super User and the Meta.

Comment: You don't have to click the number of notifications, entire "StackExchange" logo is clickable. It's only like 3% of the hitbox width that's out of the screen. (still, it is a bug)

Comment: Oh I get it, the notification counts (or SE logo with no notifications) is cut off slightly.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this in both Chrome and Firefox on Android 4.3 on my Nexus 7 (2012).  This looks like a CSS problem similar to the one described at [Moderator diamond is too large relative to other text on Android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176715/moderator-diamond-is-too-large-relative-to-other-text-on-android).  The first image is from Chrome; the second is from Firefox.  Notice how the Super User logo touches the left edge of each image.

[image: Chrome on Android]
[image: Firefox on Android]